# How to get rid of Facebook warning in Ionic/Cordova Emulator?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I'm building an App using Ionic in which I've now built a Facebook login using the [OpenFB plugin](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB). This works fine in the browser, but when I try it in the emulator, Facebook I get redirected to the FB view and I can login, but after that view I get a white screen giving me a warning which reads (translated from Dutch) something like this:

> SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Center for more information.

I don't get this warning in the browser though. Does anybody know why this is and how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

ps: my Login controller looks like this:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state){
    $scope.fbLogin = function(){
        openFB.login(
            function(response){
                if (response.status == 'connected'){
                    console.log('Facebook login succeeded. YEAH!!!');
                    $state.go('tab.chats');
                } else {
                    console.log('The FB login failed.');
                }
            },
            {scope: 'email, publish_actions'}
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix your issue? I have the same problem and still can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the In-App Browser plugin in the project and that should get it working

```
cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```